# The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, <NULL>) but I don't have that result?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm getting the following error when I try to add 3 more columns data to my existing table

```
> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.table1' with unique
> index 'IX_OL_column1_column2'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>,
> <NULL>).
```

Here is my code

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column3, column4, column5)
select t2.column3, t2.column4, t3.column5
from table1 t1
         left join [database1].dbo.table2 t2 on t1.column6 = cast(t2.column6 as nvarchar)
         left join [database2].dbo.table3 t3
                   on t1.column1 = t3.column1 and t1.column2 = t3.column2
where t1.column7 = 0
```

The thing is, when I run the select command alone while adding column1 and column2 to see the result, there is never a case where the both of them are NULL.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: What is the DDL for table1? The error suggests that it has column1 and column2 and as you are not inserting any data into these columns that is why you are getting this error

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
my syntax is wrong, it should be `UPDATE table1 SET`